# Format telephone numbers in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, formatting

I have a column of numbers in the format

`'+43 ??? ?? ??`
(the **'** is there so Excel doesn't think it's a formula and **?** represents an integer)

which I would like to have in the format

```
'+43 ?? ??? ??
```

(having the block with 3 integers in the middle instead of having it after the **'+43**)

Comment: Easiest thing to do would be to copy the column data out to Notepad++, use some regex to change the pattern, then paste it all back into Excel. As for the actual regex, i can't help with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use Excel [RegEx Find/Replace](http://www.codedawn.com/excel-add-ins.php) add-in, and with that you can use this formula to change format:
`=RegExReplace(A1,"(\+43 \d{2})(\d) ","$1 $2")`

[image]

You can see here how the regular expression part works: https://regex101.com/r/ccLkRK/1

Comment: If you are using Excel 2013 or later, or Excel 365, you can use flash fill. No add-ins necessary at all.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are using a current version of Excel (2013+ or 365). In an adjacent column, next to the input, just type out a few outputs by hand. Excel should infer the pattern and offer to Flash Fill automatically. Just press Enter, and Done!

If it does not, you can click on Fill on the Home tab, and select Flash Fill.

No Add-ins necessary.

[image]

As seen in the screenshot, 2 examples was all it took.